# Как подключить js/css файлы в модуле без применения assets (ассет менеджера)?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть отдельный модуль `documentation`. В представлении я хочу подключить `css` и `js` файлы напрямую, из любой папки этого модуля. Например они могут лежать в той же папке, что и само представление, а могу положить в папку `public/css`/`public/js`. В представлении я хочу прописать либо `<link src...>` для подключения напрямую. Но в браузере отображается ошибка 404 Not found.

В данном случае я принципиально не хочу использовать `Asset`, который наследуется от `BaseAsset` и прописывать там. Мне важно именно "чистое" подключение файлов.

Также пробовала `$this->registerCssFile` и `$this->registerJsFile`, но они тоже выдают 404 со всевозможными вариантами путей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стандартный файл `.htaccess` Yii2 можно в начале дописать:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/modules\/.*\/(.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg)
RewriteRule ^modules/(.*)$ modules/$1 [L]
```

Или такие строчки:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/modules/.*
RewriteRule ^modules/(.*)$ modules/$1 [L]
```

В первом случае мы явно перечисляем все типы файлов, а во втором это не учитываем. Судя по стандартной маршрутизации:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
```

Как раз все, что не начинается с `/web/` будет переадресовано на `web/index.php`.